# passing single object of different class to single method and then check its type

Tags: c#, api

Different Models classes have two to three common properties like token string and card number which are being used in `AuthenticateToken` method in Controllers Api.

Can i pass single generic type object to `AuthenticateToken` and check the object type in there instead of passing card and token string in all service response methods. In the future, if another property needs to be added for authentication then it can be done in `AuthenticateToken` and don't have to update all service response methods. Is there any need of doing it?

```
[HttpPost]
public ServiceResponse GetBalance(ServiceInput serviceInput)
{
   if (AuthenticateToken(serviceInput.Token, serviceInput.CardNumber))
   {
      //do something;
   }
}

[HttpPost]
public ServiceResponse CancelVoucher(InvoiceInput serviceInput)
{
   if (AuthenticateToken(serviceInput.Token, serviceInput.CardNumber))
   {
      //do something;
   }
}

[HttpPost]
public ServiceResponse AddFunds(TransferInput serviceInput)
{
   if (AuthenticateToken(serviceInput.Token, serviceInput.CardNumber))
   {
      //do something;
   }
}

 private bool AuthenticateToken(string tokenString, string cardNumber)
    {
       return (token.AuthenticateToken(tokenString, cardNumber));
    }
```

**My Idea**

```
  private bool AuthenticateToken(object _obj)
    {
        var a;

        if (_obj is ServiceInput)
        {
           ServiceInput a = _obj as ServiceInput;
            //...
        }
        else if (_obj is InvoiceInput)
        {
           InvoiceInput a = _obj as InvoiceInput;
            //...
        }
        return (_token.AuthenticateToken(a.tokenString, a.cardNumber));

    }
```

Comment: Not the best idea. You're going to create a nightmare to extend and maintain. You should prefer polymorphism to doing checks on the instance type.

Comment: I would suggest having an `IToken` interface which has a `tokenstring` readonly property and a `cardNumber` readonly provider. `ServiceInput` and `InvoiceInput` then implement `IToken`.

Comment: I'd avoid sending the auth token as a plain string. You could use the `Authorization: Bearer 'xxxxx'` header for that and check the token in a handler (before action method is executed in controller).

Comment: How does `[HttpPost]
public ServiceResponse CancelVoucher(InvoiceInput serviceInput)
{
   if (AuthenticateToken(serviceInput.Token, serviceInput.CardNumber))
   {` compile?

Comment: are you asking for inheritance ?

Comment: IToken is not an option, only two to three properties are common among different model classes. Should i keep it simply and just pass card number and token string as parameter in all controller methods?

Comment: Can i use dynamic type object? private bool AuthenticateToken(dynamic obj)